# ExoPlayer - Weird Arabic/Persian Subtitles Format

Tags: android, arabic, exoplayer, subtitle, arabic-support

I'm trying to create a video player with subtitles. everything is set up and working correctly , except one thing. my Arabic subtitles are not showing correctly as they should be. they look so weird with symbols and stuff.. something like this :

[image]

**Here's my ExoPlayer Setup with subtiltes** :

```
Uri srt = Uri.parse("http://download1651.mediafire.com/titdvyxje25g/j5wpodffdhn005r/Thor+3+.WEB+%28NoColored%29.srt");
    
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector =
            new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    player =
            ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter2 = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter2);
    Format textFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(null, MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP,
            null, Format.NO_VALUE, Format.NO_VALUE, "ar", null, Format.OFFSET_SAMPLE_RELATIVE);
    MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(getVideoUri()));
    MediaSource textMediaSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(srt, textFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);
    MediaSource mediaSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, textMediaSource);


    player.prepare(mediaSource);
```

is there any solution on how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding of that file is `windows-1256`. you should change it to Unicode first and then you can see it correctly.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("arabic sub.srt"), "windows-1256")
    );
String line = null;
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("new.srt"), "UTF-8")
);
while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){        
    writer.write(line);
    writer.write("\r\n");
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: So these lines of code are going to recreate the .srt in UTF-8? My .srt is loaded directly from the web.. Do u think that it will work? U can look above on my code that I'm using a Uri.. Please can provide me with more explanation ? Thank you

Comment: You can download the file, change its encoding using the mentioned code and then convert its local path to Uri this way: `new File(path).toURI().toURL();`

Comment: thank you, I've just converted my .srt before uploading them. i think that would be easier cause i have to edit them too.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is awesome but slight changes are required in case of Android

```
new FileOutputStream(filename.extension)
```

won't work, you will either need to use
getFilesDir()
or
getExternalFilesDir()

The latter will require
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
permission

If you are loading the srt file from network use

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(https://yoursrturl).openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Hope it helps.