# Java UTF8 encoding Subtitles Content

Tags: java, android-studio, utf-8, exoplayer, video-subtitles

I take subtitle from URL and display it in exoplayer, but the subtitle content is full of symbols because the language of the text is Arabic, Greek, Chinese, etc. How do I encode MediaScource to UTF8 before displaying it in the video?

Here is my code to prepare the content of the subtitles:

```
MediaSource subtitleSource = 
    new SingleSampleMediaSource
            .Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(
                Uri.parse(subtitlesUrl), 
                subtitleFormat, 
                C.TIME_UNSET
            )
;
```

With this code it loads the subtitles correctly but only in English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ExoPlayer - Weird Arabic/Persian Subtitles Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892533/exoplayer-weird-arabic-persian-subtitles-format)